# TypeError: $(...) is null error in admin grid pagination in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom-grid

I have pared grid in admin and have more than 20 records. Now I try to increase records par page limit from 20 to 30 but it gives js error 'TypeError: $(...) is null'.
For more detail refere images

[image]

When I select range from 20 to 30 I got error as shown bellow

[image]

If any one know then help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you please mention using which way you have created GRID ? Means is the UI component or simple

Comment: I have used simple way. I did not used UI component.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Are you able to solve it.